# Counting the number of duplicates in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

What is the quickest way to count the *maximum number* of duplicates in a list? For example, the maximum number of duplicates in {1,1,1,3} is 3, in {1,1,2,2} is 2 and in {1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3} is 3.
I've unsuccessfully tried combinations of Commonest, Count and CountDistinct. Other questions have dealt with identifying or deleting duplicates rather than counting them.

Comment: Look up `Tally`. For example, `MaximalBy[Tally[lst], Last]`.

Comment: Nice. I'd go with `Max[Tally[lst][[;; , 2]]]` which seems simpler to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
lst = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3};

ClearAll[f]
f = Max[Counts @ #] /. 1 -> 0 &;

f @ lst
```

> 3

```
f @ {1,2,3,4}
```

> 0

Comment: The problem is that e.g. {1,2,3} returns 1, but it contains no duplicates (defined as two or more ocurrences).

Comment: @spaced, good catch. Updated to get 0 when there are no duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this using `If` and `Tally`:

```
f = Function[x, If[Part[x, 2] > 1, Part[x, 2], 0]] @@ Tally[#] &;
```

Test:

```
lst1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
lst2 = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3};
lst3 = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4};
f@lst1
f@lst2
f@lst3
(*0*)
(*3*)
(*6*)
```

Or using `GroupBy`:

```
f = Max@ReplaceAll[1 -> 0][
    Normal[GroupBy[Thread[# -> Range[Length[#]]], Keys, Length]][[All, 2]]] &;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
alist = {1, 2, 3, 4};
blist = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3};
clist = {1, 1, 1, 3};
dlist = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4};

h = If[DuplicateFreeQ[#], 0, Last@First@Tally[#]] &

h /@ {alist, blist, clist, dlist}
```

> {0, 3, 3, 6}

Answer (score 3):

> I've unsuccessfully tried combinations of Commonest, Count and CountDistinct.

```
arr = {1,1,1,3};
arr // Commonest // Count[arr, First@#]&
```

> 3

just one more step :)